# Number of restaurants with specific cuisine in each country

Tags: google-api, openstreetmap, tripadvisor

I am trying to figure out how many restaurants, in each country, there are of a specific cuisine (seafood). I have looked at Google Places Api and TripAdvisor Api, but cannot find these numbers. I don´t need the list of restaurants, only number of restaurants. I found OpenStreetMap which looked very promising. I downloaded data for Norway, but the numbers are not correct (osmium tags-filter norway-latest.osm.pbf cuisine=seafood) = 62, which is way to low.
Any suggestion for how and where I can find what I am looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Extrapolate.

You won't get an accurate answer, how do you even define what a seafood restaurant is?

Find out roughly how many restaurants there are in the area you are interested in and then decide what % of them *might* be seafood restaurants.

Comment: If cuisine is 'seafood' I define it as seafood restaurant. It won´t be accurate, but that is the best I can do. I don´t even know how to figure out how many restaurants there is an area. I need the number on country basis, so doing 50 kilometer (which the above mention API supports) searches seems challenging.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this approach to extract the data from OpenStreetMap:

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/363474/aggregate-number-of-features-by-country-in-overpass

You can run the query on http://overpass-turbo.eu/ (go to settings and chose the kumi-systems server).

The query could look like this:

```
// Define fields for csv output
[out:csv(name, total)][timeout:2500];

//All countries
area["admin_level"=2];

// Count in each area
foreach->.regio(
  // Collect all Nodes with highway=milestone in the current area
  ( node(area.regio)[cuisine=seafood];
    way(area.regio)[cuisine=seafood];
    rel(area.regio)[cuisine=seafood];);

  // assemble the output
  make count name = regio.set(t["name:en"]),
             total = count(nodes) + count(ways) + count(relations);
  out;
);
```

This query can take a long time (at the time of writing, mine did not yet finish)

You can also run the query via `curl` in on some server and let the results mailed to you via `curl ....... | mail -s "Overpass Result" yourmail@example.com`. You get the `curl` command in the browser network tab by "copy curl"

I also considered Taginfo (https://taginfo.openstreetmap.org/tags/cuisine=seafood) but it cannot filter by tag.

Comment: Nice, I will try this. I have tried different approaches with Open Streem Map, but it seems like Open Street Map is missing a lot of data. I might be wrong.

Comment: Nope, the numers cannot be correct. Look at this:
France 449
Netherlands 85
Norway 19

Comment: Yes date quality varies; for sure there are not all existing restaurants in the world in OSM